# unusual java gui spam using java.awt and java.swing

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, awt

i was following a tutorial on youtube to learn java guis ands i was making a login screen.
i was testing the login button by making it print works in console w but i presses. i followed the whole tutoral properly and tried every way.  the code is spamming widows shown in the video.

link to video : https://hriday.tk/2022-01-09%2019-56-32.mkv

the code :

````
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPasswordField;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

public class Login implements ActionListener{
    public Login() {
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        JLabel Ulabel = new JLabel("UserName");
        JLabel Plabel = new JLabel("PassWord");
        JTextField Utext = new JTextField(20);
        JPasswordField Ptext = new JPasswordField(20);
        JButton login = new JButton("Login");
        JLabel success = new JLabel("");
        
        panel.setLayout(null);
        panel.add(Ulabel);
        panel.add(Utext);
        panel.add(Plabel);
        panel.add(Ptext);
        panel.add(login);
        panel.add(success);
        
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setSize(350, 150);
        frame.setTitle("Login");
        frame.add(panel);
        
        Ulabel.setBounds(10, 10, 80, 25);
        Utext.setBounds(100, 10, 165, 25);
        Plabel.setBounds(10, 40, 80, 25);
        Ptext.setBounds(100, 40, 165, 25);
        login.setBounds(50, 70, 100, 25);
        success.setBounds(200, 70, 100, 25);

        login.addActionListener(new Login());
        }
    
    public static void main(String[] args){ new Login(); }
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        System.out.println("works");
    }
} ```
````

Comment: I always suspect learning to code from videos... not adequate - videos are much more difficult to edit/correct, compared to written tutorials; videos are much harder to follow, written tutorials can be read at your speed; ...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is causing your problems:

```
// imports

public class Login implements ActionListener {
    public Login() {
        
        // .... code removed

        login.addActionListener(new Login());  // **** here ****
    }
    
    // .....
}
```

You're calling this in the Login constructor and so are creating new Login objects recursively, meaning, each time the Login constructor is called, it creates a new Login object, which calls the constructor, which creates a new Login object, which.... well, you should get the point.

Instead, change it to this:

```
login.addActionListener(this);
```

Here you add the already created Login object, the `this` object, and add it to the ActionListener.

---

## Caveat:

Having said this, I would be remiss if I didn't mention that using null layouts and `setBounds(...)` is not healthy as this makes for very inflexible GUI's that while they might look good on one platform look terrible on most other platforms or screen resolutions and that are very difficult to update and maintain. Instead, you will want to study and learn the layout managers and then nest JPanels, each using its own layout manager to create pleasing and complex GUI's that look good on all OS's.

For that reason you're far better off learning about and using the layout managers. You can find the layout manager tutorial here: [Layout Manager Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html), and you can find links to the Swing tutorials and to other Swing resources here: [Swing Info](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/swing/info).

... and if this is from a tutorial and it recommends use of null layouts, then ditch the tutorial!

For example (using GridBagLayout):

```
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.Insets;
import java.awt.Window;
import java.awt.Dialog.ModalityType;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Login2 {
    private static final int GAP = 5;
    private JPanel mainPanel = new JPanel();
    private JTextField userNameField = new JTextField(20);
    private JPasswordField passwordField = new JPasswordField(20);
    private JButton loginButton = new JButton("Login");
    private JLabel successLabel = new JLabel(" ");
    
    public Login2() {       
        mainPanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(GAP, GAP, GAP, GAP));
        mainPanel.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        
        mainPanel.add(new JLabel("UserName:"), createGBC(0, 0));
        mainPanel.add(userNameField, createGBC(1, 0));
        mainPanel.add(new JLabel("Password:"), createGBC(0, 1));
        mainPanel.add(passwordField, createGBC(1, 1));
        mainPanel.add(loginButton, createGBC(0, 2));
        mainPanel.add(successLabel, createGBC(1, 2));
        
        loginButton.addActionListener(e -> {
            successLabel.setText("Success");
            Window window = SwingUtilities.getWindowAncestor(mainPanel);
            window.dispose();
        });
    }
    
    public String getUserName() {
        return userNameField.getText();
    }
    
    public char[] getPassword() {
        return passwordField.getPassword();
    }
    
    // create constraints that help position components in the GridBagLayout-using container
    private GridBagConstraints createGBC(int x, int y) {
        GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc.gridx = x;
        gbc.gridy = y;
        gbc.insets = new Insets(GAP, GAP, GAP, GAP);
        return gbc;     
    }
    
    public JPanel getMainPanel() {
        return mainPanel;
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> {
            Login2 login2 = new Login2();
            
            JDialog dialog = new JDialog(null, "Login", ModalityType.APPLICATION_MODAL);
            dialog.setDefaultCloseOperation(JDialog.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
            
            dialog.add(login2.getMainPanel());
            dialog.pack();
            dialog.setLocationByPlatform(true);
            dialog.setVisible(true);
            
            System.out.println("User Name: " + login2.getUserName());
            System.out.println("Password:  " + new String(login2.getPassword()));
            
        });
    }
}
```